# Eager loading relationship returns empty using SELECT in WITH clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Using **Laravel 5.4**, I have a query that correctly returns a relationship. Using the "with" clause in the query, I am attempting to return only selected columns from the relationship in my controller.

When I add the **select** to the **with** clause, relationship returns an empty array. Oddly enough, if I add a different parameter, such as a **groupBy** or **join** the query DOES return results. So something about my setup dislikes the **select** on the query.

Thus far I have tried:

- using **selectRaw**
- using **select(DB::raw)**
- tried defining this as a separate relationship on my model.

Nothing has worked this far. Sql log looks good when I dump it.

Here is my model:

```
// MODEL
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class ClassBlocks extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function schedule(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClassSchedules', 'class_block_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
//CONTROLLER
use App;
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProgramsController extends Controller
{
    public function filterClass(Request $request, App\ClassBlocks $block)
    {

        $block = $block->newQuery();

        // Attempt to eager load relationship
        // Returns results when "select" disabled
        $block->with([
            'schedule' => function($query){
                $query->select('time_start');
                $query->groupBy('day');
            },
        ]);

        return $block->get();

    }
}
```

Here is a sample result with select enabled (schedule returns empty):

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "program_id": "1",
    "class_group_id": "1",
    "schedule": [

    ]
  }
]
```

And here is a result with select disabled (returns relationship when select disabled):

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "program_id": "1",
    "class_group_id": "1",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "id": 338,
        "class_group_id": "1",
        "program_id": "1",
        "class_block_id": "13",
        "date": "06/13/2017",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "instructor_id": "1",
        "time_start": "6:30am",
        "time_end": "6:30am"
      },
      {
        "id": 339,
        "class_group_id": "1",
        "program_id": "1",
        "class_block_id": "13",
        "date": "06/14/2017",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "instructor_id": "2",
        "time_start": "6:30am",
        "time_end": "6:30am"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is:

```
$query->select('time_start');
```

Laravel need to have column that is connection between 2 records. In this case you should probably use:

```
$query->select('time_start', 'class_block_id');
```

to make it work.

Obviously you will have `class_block_id` in response this way. If you really don't want it, probably you should create some transformer that will return exactly you want in response.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I guess I was a bit confused because I've eager loaded relationships like this in the past without requiring an identifying key.

Not quite sure what the difference between the two models is, but I'll have to investigate further.